# Testing individual nodes launched by naught using supertest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node.js, express.js

The purpose: an express node.js server which can be launched using naught, with an integration test using supertest. Each worker naught runs will test itself on a unique port, and only if passes it will listen in on the main port and join the pool.

Major concerns are - no idea what I'm doing.  How I provision the ports for the test nodes, closing the test servers (need to clear up memory)?

This just a POC, structuring is required for a production app.

```
var testport = 10000 + process.pid;
var server = app.listen(testport, function() {
    console.log('pid %d listening on port %d ...', process.pid, testport);

    supertest(server)
    .get('/test')
    .expect(200)
    .end(function(err, res){

        if (err) {
            console.log(err); 
            if (process.send) process.send('offline');
            process.exit(-1);
        }
        else {
            console.log('pid %d tested OK, closing test server and launching main one...', process.pid);
            server.close();
            listenToMainport();                
        }

    });
});
```

You can see the full context of the example [here](https://gist.github.com/avnersorek/ae36e1de73bca2a8e188).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write more code before submitting, the fun part to review is the code that you wrote after the prototype ;)

From a quick once over:

- JsHint finds no fault except for some mixed use of tabs and space
- Consider `'use strict'`, it can save lives
- Consider something better than `console.log`, especially if you are going to use this code for performance testing
- Use lowerCamelCase consistently: `testport` -> `testPort`

Answer (score 1):

Supertest is a great tool. You don't actually have to run it on a test port as it does that for you, but it won't hurt.

I have found these tools useful for testing my node server endpoints:

- [Mocha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha) to run the tests. Install this a -g global module.
- [Chai](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai) is used to make assertions against test result. This is better than using console.log for sure. This module would need to be required in the test file.
- [should](https://www.npmjs.com/package/should) is another alternative for making assertions against your results.